# A strange TypeLoadException

Tags: c#, .net

I wan't implement a struct tree, but i got a TypeLoadException.

```
Console.WriteLine(typeof(Node)); // throw TypeLoadException

public struct Node
{
    public StructList<Node> Sons;
}
public struct StructList<T>
{
}
```

Comment: Interesting -- this fails under both .NET 4.8 and 6, generating an assembly that `peverify` doesn't like either, but tools like ildasm and ILSpy have no trouble processing. This is pretty much a minimal reproduction: the exact scenario that fails is a value type `V` containing a field of a generic value type `GV<T>` that's parameterized with `V` itself. If `GV` is a `class`, there is no issue, nor if `T` is a type other than `V`. It doesn't matter if `GV` is defined in the same assembly or a different one, it's specifically `V` that fails.

Comment: This appears to be [runtime#72039](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/72039) and [runtime#6924](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/6924) -- an old bug that has seen little work, because the issue is apparently quite fundamental.

Answer (score -1):

I resolved.

```
public unsafe class Node
{
    private StructList _children;

    public ref StructList<Node> Children => ref Unsafe.AsRef<StructList<Node>>(Unsafe.AsPointer(ref _children));

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct StructList
    {
        private IntPtr _array;
        private int _size;
        private int _length;
    }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct StructList<T>
{
    private IntPtr _array;
    private int _size;
    private int _length;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).